# Django - Is there a way to configure certain url to be inaccessible from browser request?

Tags: django, django-views

I've searched for this question but could not found an answer.

Basically, let's say i have `my_app/successfully_page` that i want to be displayed within the application flow. I don't want that to be displayed if some one is typing into browser the direct url.

How can i make that url page INACCESSIBLE from browser search?

Comment: Please post code examples with it.

Comment: Hi, i don't know what code example to post. Basically, i have 1 url that i want to be inaccessible from browser search bar. Url like that `path('simulations/successful/', views.Simulations.as_view(), name='Success',),` in urls.py. The Aurelian's answer i think is what i needed, you can check it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` in order to check from which url the user is coming. If this is not the authorized url, then you can redirect the user:

```
if request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') == my_url:
    # Do something...
else:
    # Redirect...
```

Check the doc here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Comment: Yes, i saw what you sugest. It works, thank you! Just for the record.. is there any solution regarding settings.py or something like that?

Comment: If you want to use this on all the views, consider building  a middleware

Answer (score 0):

I had some kind of same problem before , I solved it using sessions in the page before that set a session on the request and in the views of the url which needs to be inaccessible by direct browser set a if condition on it.
This need to be set in view of before page

```
request.session['is_accessible'] = True
```

And in the page u want to make the condition like

```
if (request.session['is_accessible'] == True):
        redirect("Your_page_url.html")
else:
        redirect("Page you want to show .html")
```

And if you are thinking that a page needs to be accessed only on login then there is a decorator in Django itself like

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/login.html')
def yourfunction(request):
     return Httpresponse("Your page")
```

And if u have more problem in it u can write an email to me at kiranu941@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You have to use user agent that will let you know the perfect output.

```
request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

But I would also recommend you to take a look at the [Django User-Agents](https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents) library.

You can find more relevant examples over the link.